Maximum value of $f(x, y, z) = yz + xz + xy − 2xyz$ for $x, y, z \ge 1$
I know I should try to explore a limit such as $\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow(\infty,a, b)} f(x,y,z)$ where $a,b$ are some constants. Is it true that I can directly replace $y$ and $z$ in the limit by way of continuity? Then the limit would become $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(a+b)x + ab - 2abx = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (a-2ab+b)x + ab = \pm\infty$ depending on $a,b$ therefore the function cannot have a maximum value. I'm fairly certain my thinking is wrong but I don't know how to proceed with this problem. Please help.
EDIT:
Calculating the 1st partial derivatives like so:
$\begin{cases}f'_x = z + y - 2zy = 0\\f'_y = x + z - 2xz = 0\\f'_z = x + y - 2xy = 0\end{cases}$
$f'_y - f'_z = (z-y) - 2x(z-y) = (1-2x)(z-y)$ where the only solution is $z=y$ since $x \ge 1 \implies x\neq 1/2$. Then substituting into the first two equations I get:
$\begin{cases}x+y-2xy=0\\2y-2y^2=0\iff y(1-y)(1+y) = 0\end{cases}$
The only solution is $y=1$ since the other fall outside of the possible values for $y$. Then going back to $f'_y$ I get $x + 1 - 2x = 0 \iff x = 1$. Therefore there is a critical point at $(1,1,1)$. However $f''_{xx} = 0$ which means you can't tell anything about what kind of point it is solely off of the derivative test. How can I proceed from here?

The function can be rewritten as
$$f(x,y,z) = (1-x)(1-y)(1-z) + x + y + z - 1 - xyz$$
$$\implies f(u,v,w) = -uvw + u + v + w + 2 -(u+1)(v+1)(w+1) = 1 - uv - vw - uw - 2uvw$$
where $u,v,w\geq 0$. Since the terms on the right are all nonpositive, we know the maximum of the function is $\boxed{\max f = 1}$

To advance this further, the maximum occurs when $u=v=w=0$ and thus $x=y=z=1$.

Very clever solution. I like it!

The function is linear in each variable, so the extrema happens at the end points.
We just need to check value at the 8 end points of the form $\{ 1 , \infty \} ^3 $, to conclude that $ f(1, 1, 1, ) = 1$ is the maximum.

How can I calculate a limit such as $\lim_{(x,y,z)\rightarrow(\infty,1,1)} f(x,y,z)$? Can I replace the $y$ and $z$ values with 1 directly since it doesn't cause an indeterminate form?

@Marinm You treat it like any other limit. If only 1 term goes to infinity, then yes you can replace. $\quad$ If 2 or more terms goes to infinity, then one has to be careful about how they tend to infinity. EG Observe that if $ x, y, z \geq 2$, then $f(x, y, z) \leq 0 $.

For box constraints, it is often helpful to pick the point with lowest variable values, and from that point explore all possible directions.
In this case, this base point is $v=(1,1,1)^T$. A direction now is a vector $d\in\mathbb R$ where not all elements are zero (and optionally with norm 1). And an allowed direction further has $d\ge 0$. Now, all points have the form $v+dt$ for some $t\ge 0$.
Formally:
$$\forall \{\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}\in\mathbb R^3\mid x,y,z\ge 1\} :\exists d\in\mathbb R^3\setminus\pmatrix{0\\0\\0}\exists t\in\mathbb R_{\ge 0}:\quad f\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} =f(v+dt) $$
Substituting in we get
$$
 g(t)= f(v+dt)
\\=- 2t^3d_1d_2d_3 - t^2d_2d_3 - t^2d_1d_3 - t^2d_1d_2 + 1
$$
Because $t,d\ge 0$, it is easy to see that all summands but the $+1$ are non-positive, so $f(0)=1$ is the function's maximum.
